# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2151','1886' to data type int

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the below query

```
  DEClare @Plan_ID nvarchar(100)
  set @Plan_ID=REPLACE('2151,1886',',',''',''')
```

and

```
SELECT distinct  Plan_Dict_Id from REF_Plan_Dictionary WHERE 
   CAST(Plan_Dict_Id as int) in (@Plan_ID),
```

Pls help , `Plan_Dict_Id` datatype is `INT`, I want to pass the values to where , but getting error "Conversion failed when converting the `varchar` value '2151','1886' to data type int."

Comment: There is no nvarchar datatype in mysql , with the other tags this looks more like a sqlserver question.

Comment: please update the tags and confirm the database you are using and also the version.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one of the later versions of SQL Server then you could do something like this...

```
DECLARE @Plan_ID nvarchar(100) 
SET @Plan_ID= '2151,1886'

SELECT DISTINCT Plan_Dict_Id 
    FROM REF_Plan_Dictionary d
        JOIN string_split(@Plan_ID, ',') s ON d.Plan_Dict_Id = s.[value]
```

If you are using an older version you could put the whole statement in a string and then execute it, however you have a problem in your first line as you are not adding quotes around the string... I've accounted for that below.

```
DEClare @Plan_ID nvarchar(100) set @Plan_ID=REPLACE('2151,1886',',',''',''') 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'select distinct Plan_Dict_Id from REF_Plan_Dictionary where CAST(Plan_Dict_Id as int) in (''' + @Plan_ID + ''')'
EXEC (@sql)
```